# How does roundcube color the emails and how to implement the roundcube color scheme in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, roundcube

RoundCube gives a nice color scheme for the plain-text email below.

I am wondering how does RoundCube do this, and how to implement this color scheme in Delphi ?

```
>>>> Peter says: 
>>>> Peter says: 
>>> Jane says:
>>> Jane says:
>> Peter says: 
>> Peter says:
> Jane says:
> Jane says:
Peter says: 
Peter says:
```

[image: roundcube]

Comment: It's not that nice if you look at the same color for the 4 inner messages from 2 different people :) Besides, I would use a common rich edit control and for those thread lines I would use `│` chars (actually, each `>` char from the line start could be converted to `│` char where each will differ in color depending on thread levels).

Comment: Which part are you finding difficult?

Comment: @TLama Thank you for your comments! The replacement of ">" by "|" is a good idea! It should be noted that in the roundcube version, the vertical lines are not selectable. Could you help to comment ? (Indeed the color is the same for the inner/older messages... Great catch!)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The vertical lines (which cannot be selected), and the definition of color scheme. :D

Comment: Looks like a custom control to me. Color scheme is easy. Blue, then green, then everything else red. Kind of lame really.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A text control that can draw lines in its background and can indent text ? At least the color is much more appealing than plain text ? ...

Comment: Should be rather straightforward to reproduce a layout like that with HTML and CSS. Put each level of quote in a nested `div` (or even nested `blockquote`, if those are allowed to be nested), and arrange border colors and padding based on nesting level in CSS. The hardest part will be parsing the text to identify blocks of text from the same level.

Comment: That's a pretty solid idea from Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea how RoundCube does it; I'm not familiar with the product. The effect is straightforward to achieve with HTML and CSS, though.

I used nested `blockquote` elements for the e-mail quotes:

```html
<blockquote>
  <blockquote>
    <blockquote>
      <blockquote>
        <blockquote>
          <blockquote>
            Peter says:<br/>
            Peter says:
          </blockquote>
          Jane says:<br/>
          Jane says:
        </blockquote>
        Peter says:<br/>
        Peter says:
      </blockquote>
      Jane says:<br/>
      Jane says:
    </blockquote>
    Peter says:<br/>
    Peter says
  </blockquote>
  Jane says:<br/>
  Jane says:
</blockquote>
Peter says:</br>
Peter says:
```

Then I colored the borders and text according to the nesting level in CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Times';
}
blockquote {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-left: 3px solid #00f;
  border-right: 3px solid #00f;
  color: #00f;
  padding: 0.6em 0.9em 0.3em;
  margin: 0 0 0.3em;
}
blockquote > blockquote {
  color: #0f0;
  border-color: #0f0;
}
blockquote > blockquote > blockquote {
  color: #b22;
  border-color: #b22;
}
```

You can look at [a live demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/10403926).

RoundCube is a Web e-mail program, so you could look at the HTML it generates, if you wanted to confirm this is how it works.

The hardest part about the task would be parsing the e-mail to identify blocks of text from the same level, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and efforts ! The live demo is fantanstic !